# Google Colab "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

Since yesterday I have been trying to run a git project in Google Collab. However, I have the problem that it does not recognize the modules. However, the modules are stored in Drive. With another account without the Pro version, everything worked perfectly.

2023-11-19 13:11:41.722619: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9342] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2023-11-19 13:11:41.722685: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:609] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2023-11-19 13:11:41.722737: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1518] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2023-11-19 13:11:43.215387: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/content/drive/MyDrive/apbench/poisons_generate.py", line 13, in 
from attack import ar_poisons, dc_poisons, em_poisons, hypo_poisons, lsp_poisons, ops_poisons, rem_poisons, tap_poisons, ntga_poisons
File "/content/drive/MyDrive/apbench/attack/ntga_poisons.py", line 6, in 
from data.ntga_base.attacks.projected_gradient_descent import projected_gradient_descent
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'

Comment: Please include code and error messages in your question as text and not as images!

Comment: As I know, in order to use user defined modules in colab, you must upload your modules to the current working directory. This is where, you can find when you click the folder icon in the left pane when opening a colab file.

Comment: Just bear in mind that, this space is volatile. After disconnecting from runtime, the files are deleted automatically, meaning having to upload the modules for everytime you need them.